# Android aar library reference

Tags: android, android-studio

I struggle serveral days for researching how to use the andorid `aar library` in my project,

- OS : mac osx
- Android device : MI PAD2
- Build Env.: Android studio v1.1 beta 4

*Step 1*, I converted two eclipse project (one lib & one app) into "Project" in Android studio .

build.gradle is done & everything is ok.

*Step 2*, I import aar project generated in path below! https://i.stack.imgur.com/k7AKt.png

you can see outputs folder, `xx-debug.aar & xx-release.aar`

*Step 3.*

I removed this line

```
// compile project(":libs:xXBWhiteBoard")
```

in `"app"` module .

And import `xxDebug.aar` into my app module;
it crashed when open an activity.

Error log shows:

> ClassNotFoundException WhiteBoardActivity$WBPoint

when I use `xxRelease.aar`,

> Class in aar cannot be used by "import com.xxb.WhiteBoardActivity"

gradle build is failed .

My question is: how could I suppose to use aar library in project or if there is something wrong with my process.